# Dbus connection through mod_wsgi in python

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to write small application which allows to send dbus commands (to Amarok) through web page. 
I'm using python + mod_wsgi, because I need to run the script with the same user as Amarok.

When I connect to the Amarok through normal shell, it works. But after connecting through the script, I get the following error:

```
DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
```

The code which is connecting to the Amarok:

```
import dbus
conn = dbus.SessionBus().get_object('org.kde.amarok','/Player')
```

Do you know what should I do to connect through dbus to Amarok?
Thanks a lot for help!

Update:
I'll give you some additional information about configuration:
httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module  modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIScriptAlias /amarok /var/www/amarok-python/config.wsgi
WSGIDaemonProcess l user=wojtas group=wojtas processes=1
WSGIProcessGroup l
```

config.WSGI:

```
import sys
path='/var/www/amarok-python'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
import index
application=index.application
```

Code of the application (index.py):

```
import dbus
from os import getuid
def connect():
        conn = dbus.SessionBus().get_object('org.kde.amarok','/Player')
        conn.Start()
        return conn
def application(environ,start_response):
    status= '200 OK'
    connection=connect()
    output=str(getuid())
    response_headers= [('Content-type','text/html'), ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response (status,response_headers)
    return [output]
```

Comment: nobody? I didn't find answer so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't set the DISPLAY variable, which is required for connecting with dbus.
You can check the small tutorial on this webpage:
http://blog.wojtass.pl/tutorial-control-amarok-remotely-through-web-browser/